# I can't expand the template django

Tags: python, django, templates

I can't expand the template `base.html` template `header.html`

Content  `base.html`

```
<div id="main-container">
  <!-- HEADER -->
  {% block header %}{% endblock %}
  <!-- END HEADER -->
</div>
```

Content  `header.html`

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block header %}
<header id="header">
***
</header>
{% endblock %}
```

The output in the browser get the code:

```
<div id="main-container">
  <!-- HEADER -->

  <!-- END HEADER -->
```

Why not be able to extend the template?
Using `{% include "blog/header.html"%}` code inserted. using `extends` no.
Use Django 1.10.1

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
        post = get_object_or_404 (Post, pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'blog/base.html', {'post': post})

def header(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/header.html')
```

Through
`{% include "blog/header.html" %}` works. So the way spelled out correctly.

Thought the error here:

`def header(request):
    return(request, 'blog/header.html')`

`def header(request):
    render(request, 'blog/header.html')`

`def header(request):
    return render_to_response (request, 'blog/header.html')`

Not working (((

Comment: what is the url that you are hitting?

Comment: Above code will work surely...

Comment: Which of those views is your url actually pointing to?

Comment: `/home/linux/Mysait/MysaitProject/blog/templates/blog/header.html`

and

`/home/linux/Mysait/MysaitProject/blog/templates/blog/base.html`

Comment: Views.py

`/home/linux/Mysait/MysaitProject/blog/templates/blog/views.py`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend some template, you should render template with {% extends ... %} tag (in your case header.html), if you want to include something to renedered template, you should use {% include ... %} tag. You can make new template for particular page and ovreload {% block head %}, for example:

base.html:

```
{% block header %}
{% include 'std_header.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

{% block footer%}
{% endblock %}
```

And particular page, for example landing page will overload default header:

landing.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header %}
{% include 'landing_header.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!-- landing page content -->
{% endblock %}
```

So for view called landing_page you have to render landing.html template.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have confused between the include and extend in django templates.

Based on your file names, I assume that `header.html` is the partial which is to be included in the base.html and you are rendering `base.html` .

Django templating engine does not work this way.

Use [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include) `{% include "path/to/header.html" %}` in `base.html` and juse have the header html in `header.html`.

Comment: I have a header on all pages the same. So I don't suitable connection method via  include.

Include - i'll use it to connect unique blocks (rare on the site) Less load.